# How can I see which versions of a JSFiddle are available?

Tags: jsfiddle

JSFiddle uses urls in the form of `http://jsfiddle.net/<user>/<script>/<revision>/` where revision is an incremental number. Is there any way to see other revisions of a script easily via a GUI interface or is the only way to manipulate the URL?

Is there any easy way to know how many revisions a script has without needing to manually increment the variable and check to see if a script exists there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to know how many versions of a script you have is to press the delete button near the script in your dashboard. It will warn you with a message such as the following:

> You're about to permanently delete <script>, and <num> of its revisions.

Another way is to update the script which will cause the script to use the latest revision number available in the URL.

Answer (score 5):

If it's one of your own fiddles it displays on your [dashboard](http://jsfiddle.net/user/dashboard/). There you'll see latest revision with a link.

EDIT: The GUI is updated but the functionality seems the same in this matter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can query [JSFiddle API](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/api/) to get an user's fiddles, it returns a JSONP with a `latest_version` (the number of revisions) for each fiddle.  Add your user name to the following URL to see the results:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/api/user/{USERNAME}/demo/list.json?start=0&limit=10
```

As I was missing easy access to my revisions, I made a userscript to show them on the Public fiddles page of *any user*, it runs on all `http://jsfiddle.net/user/*` URLs that are not the dashboard (`/user/dashboard/`).

<kbd>[image: user public fiddles]</kbd>

Note that the API only returns public fiddles, the ones that have a name set on *Fiddle Options*. After setting this name, it takes a while before it appears on the API.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Observations:

- While testing, I found fiddles with two thousand revisions, so I'm limiting the total revisions shown to the latest 50. To remove this feature, delete line 43 as can be seen in [this **Gist copy**](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/70ba14a134cd18b90270#file-jsfiddle-revisions-js-L43) of the script bellow.
- The script is Chrome only (I use [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/)). I don't know how to use it on Firefox, tried but failed.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Show JSFiddle revisions for each fiddle
// @namespace      webapps.se
// @author         brasofilo
// @include        http://jsfiddle.net/user/*
// @description    Add revision history to all JSFiddle public user pages 
// @require       //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

/* Stores the API list result */
jsf_titles = [];

/**
 * Sometimes the Revision URL is anonymous, without /username/
 * this function tests the URL before navigating
 * if it is a 404, we strip the username from the URL
 * 
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/22097991/1287812
 */
testRevisionURL = function( url ) 
{
    var request;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    request.open('GET', url, false);
    request.send();
    if (request.status === 404) {
        window.location = url.replace( dashboardPage() + '/', '' );
    } else {
        window.location = url;
    }
}

/**
 * Build the Revision links
 */
appendRevisionLinks = function( $div, $entry ) {
    if( parseInt( $entry.version ) > 0 ) {
        var start = 1;
        var total = parseInt( $entry.version );
        if( total > 50 ) start = total - 50;
        $div.parent().next('p.info').append( ' - Revisions: | ' );
        for (i = start; i <= total; i++) { 
            var click_url = ' onClick="testRevisionURL(\'' + $entry.url + i + '\')"';
            $div.parent().next('p.info').append( '<a href="javascript:void(0)" ' + click_url + '><b style="font-size:.8em">' + i + '</b></a> | ' );
        }
    } else {
        $div.parent().next('p.info').append( ' - No revisions ' );
    }
}

/**
 * Callback for jQuery loaded
 * Search all fiddle titles on the page and compare with the API list
 */
function jqueryCallback() {
    jQ('.fiddleList .item h3 a:first-child').each(function() { 
        var $this = jQ(this);
        var $url = $this.attr('href');
        jsf_titles.forEach(function(entry) {
            if( entry.url.indexOf($this.attr('href')) > -1 ) {
                appendRevisionLinks( $this, entry );
                jsf_titles.remove(entry);
            }
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Load jQuery and do callback when jQuery has finished loading
 * Note, jQ replaces $ to avoid conflicts.
 * 
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/3550261/1287812
 */
function addJQuery(callback) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js");
    script.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.textContent = "window.jQ=jQuery.noConflict(true);(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }, false);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

/**
 * JSFiddle API callback function
 * Builds jsf_titles custom array with JSONP result
 */
fiddleObjects = function( json ){
    json.list.forEach(function(entry) {
        jsf_titles.push({'title': entry.title, 'version': entry.latest_version, 'url': entry.url });
    });
    addJQuery( jqueryCallback );
};

/**
 * Call API
 * 
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/2887218/1287812
 */
callApi = function( user, page )
{
    var elm = document.createElement("script");
    elm.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    var start = (page - 1) * 10;
    elm.src = "http://jsfiddle.net/api/user/" + user + "/demo/list.json?callback=fiddleObjects&order=desc&start=" + start + "&limit=10";
    document.body.appendChild(elm);
}

/**
 * Remove element from array
 * http://www.simonewebdesign.it/how-to-remove-element-from-array/
 */
Array.prototype.remove = function(value) {
    var idx = this.indexOf(value);
    if (idx != -1) {
        return this.splice(idx, 1); // The second parameter is the number of elements to remove.
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Which page of the Dashboard we're in
 * not used yet, but useful if start and limit are to be used on the API request
 */
actualPage = function(){
    var pathname = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    if( pathname[pathname.length-2] == "dashboard" )
        return 1;
    else {
        var pagenum = parseInt( pathname[pathname.length-2] );
        return isNaN( pagenum ) ? 1 : pagenum;
    }
}

/**
 * Public page or dashboard
 */
dashboardPage = function(){
    var pathname = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    if( pathname[2] == "dashboard" )
        return false;
    else
        return pathname[2];
}

/**
 * Start up
 */
if( dashboardPage() ) {
    callApi( dashboardPage(), actualPage() );
    // alert('user name: ' + dashboardPage() + "\n page:" + actualPage() );
}
```